# Get the Full Path with Server Name

Tags: windows, cmd, filepath

I'm using the Windows command prompt syntax below:

```
dir/a:d/b/s >test.txt
```

The result is:

```
V:\Production\123456789
```

I need to get the below result that shows the server name instead of the Windows directory name:

```
\\nvaures001\wm_ars_res_prod_sy$\Production\123456789
```

Can anyone tell me how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are in DOS you should be able to use the command Truename to get the information you need. [Wikipedias article of DOS commands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_DOS_commands#TRUENAME)